# Chrome rendering inline-block height wrongly

Tags: javascript, html, css

So what I need is to place a plenty of inputs inside a div and they must fulfill the div.

In the firefox using the inline-block works fine, but in chrome it has a weird behavior as can be seen in plunker: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qrcGYQnmLZJfNrqOYjSy?p=preview)

```
.cl {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: monospace;
    background: black;
    width: 50px;
    height: calc(14.24px);
    display: block;
    border: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    outline: 0 !important;
    outline-offset: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Does anyone know a fix for that?

Comment: I've placed another div with display block inputs to compare.

Comment: `height: calc(14.24px);` has no sense, write `height: 14.24px;`. Because `calc()` is a function to make calculations with different units (for example `calc(100% - 24px)`

Comment: I know calc(fixed px) doesn't make sense, I was just trying things and forgot to rollback this change

Comment: If I may just ask, just out of curiosity, what are you trying to build? Some sort of code editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `vertical-align: top;` or any other `vertical-align` value to your `inline-block` elements.

Also, `calc(14.24px)` makes no sense, use simply `height: 14px;`
Also, avoid the use of `!important` (there's almost no reason to use it if your CSS is well structured)

Comment: I see that with 14px works fine, why can't I use 14.24px?

Comment: @AMagyar cause a pixel is a pixel.

Comment: @AMagyar I don't know if Chrome might have included sup-pixel precision, but if you want to build a reliable crossbrowser application, stick to integer pixels.